# How can I make the code about structure and pointer

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedf struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
} STR;

int main(void)
{
    STR *arr[4];
    STR **ptr=arr;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        arr[i]=(STR*)malloc(sizeof(STR));
        (*arr[i]).a=i+7;
        (**(ptr+i)).b=i+3;
    }
    printf("%d\n", ptr[2]->a);
    printf("%d", (*(arr+3))->b);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I make the correct code and it can compile, also I want to know what is wrong at my code.

Comment: `typedf` -> `typedef`, and your program leaks memory. You'll have to be more specific if there's anything else you're asking about.

Comment: Aside from the typos already mentioned, it does 'run' but its not at all clear what you  expect the code to do.  What should the output be?  The `ptr` and pointer dereferencing (`(*arr[i]).a`) is unnecessary, and could be written as `arr[i]->a`, likewise for the uses of `ptr` which is just referring to `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the misspelled `typedef` and that it leaks memory, it's not wrong. It's however doing the dereferencing in overly complex ways.

Suggested simplifications and notes:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Size(x) (sizeof (x) / sizeof *(x))  // to not have to hardcode `4` in the loops

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} STR;

int main(void) {
    STR *arr[4];
    STR **ptr = arr;                          // same as: &arr[0];
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Size(arr); i++) {  // use the helper macro
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof *arr[i]);      // same as: sizeof(STR)
        arr[i]->a = i + 7;                    // simpler dereferencing
        ptr[i]->b = i + 3;                    // simpler dereferencing
    }
    
    printf("%d\n", ptr[2]->a);                // simpler dereferencing
    printf("%d\n", arr[3]->b);                // simpler dereferencing

    // and finally, free the allocated memory:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Size(arr); i++) {  // use the helper macro again
        free(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
9
6
```

Comment: Thanks to you, I think I can study C language more enjoyable!

Comment: @SOooo Glad to hear it! It's a lovely language!

Answer (score -1):

You misspelled `typedef`. Otherwise, it should work. Other criticisms:

- Why are you casting the return value of `malloc()`?
- `ptr + i == &arr[i]`
- If your compiler doesn't support C99, you'll need to remove the initial declaration from the for loop.

Comment: re casting malloc, most compilers will complain e.g. `error: assigning to 'STR *' from incompatible type 'void *'`

Comment: Oh, weird. For me (GCC 11) I don't get errors or warnings. (I believe this is a C++-ism.)

Comment: You might not have all warnings enabled for the compile.

Comment: @DaveMeehan: Assigning`void *` to `STR *` is explicitly permitted by the C standard, in C 2018 6.5.16.1 1: “One of the following shall hold: … the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and … one operand is a pointer to an object type, and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void,…” C compilers generally will not warn about this. The rules are different in C++, and C++ compilers will issue a warning or error for it. Common advice for C is not to cast the result of `malloc` because it can hide an error if `<stdlib.h>` has not been included.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh, you're right; my bad - about to edit to correct this.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks again for the clarification.  My experience has been with [MISRA](https://www.misra.org.uk) and developing for embedded applications where this is an advisory, and yes, probably exists within C++ rather than C standards and implementations.  Personally I favour casting from void to make it explicit what the expected source type is, and so as a general rule don't see this warning regards lack of cast when coding (beyond the fact that MISRA lint checking will warn about the cast for different reasons!)

Comment: @DaveMeehan MISRA has different guidelines for C and C++ though. If I remember correctly, the one for C++ says _"don't use `malloc`"_, but I could be remembering it wrong.